# Why does function GetEVM set the balance of from address to MaxBig256?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm

As you can see in [this line](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/40cdcf8c47ff094775aca08fd5d94051f9cf1dbb/les/api_backend.go#L114),

```
func (b *LesApiBackend) GetEVM(ctx context.Context, msg core.Message, state *state.StateDB, header *types.Header) (*vm.EVM, func() error, error) {
    state.SetBalance(msg.From(), math.MaxBig256)
    context := core.NewEVMContext(msg, header, b.eth.blockchain, nil)
    return vm.NewEVM(context, state, b.eth.chainConfig, vm.Config{}), state.Error, nil
}
```

The `GetEVM` function has a side-effect that sets the balance of from address to MaxBig256. What's the logic behind it?

Answer (score 2):

This is only the temporary EVM for running tnx to get the value then it doesn't make and changes in the state/blockchain